# Arduino 10bit ADC is not accurate?

Tags: adc, voltage-divider

I'm reading the voltage with voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWqACt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
 <sup>| *Arduino is connected to both USB and a 9V adapter.*</sup>

```
float r1 = 100000;
float r2 = 9980;
float adc, voltage, analog;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    analog += analogRead(A0);
  }
  analog = analog / 256;
  adc = analog * 1.228 / 1023;
  voltage = adc / (r2 / (r1 + r2));
  Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(analog);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(adc);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay(100);
}
```

Here's the accuracy test result:

```
Input | Arduino | Difference
 1V      0.89V     -110mV
 2V      1.90V     -100mV
 3V      2.92V     -80mV
 4V      3.93V     -70mV
 5V      4.95V     -50mV
 6V      5.97V     -30mV
 7V      6.98V     -20mV
 8V      8.00      0
 9V      9.01      +10mV
 10V     10.02     +20mV
 11V     11.04     +40mV
 12V     12.06     +60mV
```

<sup>*The input voltages measured by DMM and was spot on voltage, like 1.000V.*</sup>

I didn't test voltages above 12V but it seems the difference is gonna increase by 20mV with each 1V increase, that means at 50V voltage reading is gonna be off by ~1V!

Even with 10bit resolution of Arduino I should have had steady accuracy with some percentage of difference(right?), but as you can see the result shows that the reading is not steady at all!

Why the voltage difference decrease/increase when voltage changes at the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Majenko, the ADC can *in principle* have all sorts of
errors. However, if you look at your data, you should notice that the
error is essentially linear with the voltage. This means that the
non-linearity error is quite small, and you are mainly seeing the offset
and gain errors. This is fortunate, because these errors are easy to
remove, given good calibration data.

The table you wrote in in your question happens to be a perfectly good
calibration table. By fitting a straight line to it you can get a
calibration function, and then correct the readings simply by adding
this to your code:

```cpp
voltage = 0.9848815 * voltage + 0.125354;
```

Or you could instead figure out the correction at the ADC level and
replace

```cpp
adc = analog * 1.228 / 1023;
```

by

```cpp
adc = (analog + offset) / scale;
```

where `offset` and `scale` are computed from the calibration.

---

**Edit**: Here is how I extracted the calibration coefficients from the
data.

First, I saved the data in a text file calibration.tsv and cleaned it up
to remove the units and add a comment marker (#) in front of the column
labels:

```
#Input | Arduino | Difference
 1      0.89     -110e-3
 2      1.90     -100e-3
...
```

Then I looked at the data with [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.info/). Since I want to know how to
correct the readings, I plot the amount I have to add (minus column 3)
v.s. the Arduino reading (column 2):

```
plot 'calibration.tsv' using 2:(-$3)
```

At this point it appears it's linear with what looks like mostly
quantization noise. I model this as a line of equation `a*x+b`, and
compare the line with the data:

```
a = -1e-2
b = 0.12
plot 'calibration.tsv' using 2:(-$3), a*x+b
```

The line is quite off the data, but it's a reasonable first
approximation. Now I ask gnuplot to perform a least squares fit, then
take another look:

```
fit a*x+b 'calibration.tsv' using 2:(-$3) via a, b
replot
```

Now the fit looks quite good. When it completed the fit, gnuplot
displayed:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -0.0151185       +/- 0.0002953    (1.953%)
b               = 0.125354         +/- 0.002173     (1.734%)
```

so now I know I can correct the data with:

```cpp
voltage += -0.0151185 * volatage + 0.125354;
```

which is equivalent to what I wrote above.

Comment: How do you calculate the offset and scale?

Comment: @newbie, put the data in Excel/Calc, draw a chart with expected values and function  and then change the offset and scale values for the function until the lines in the chart match

Comment: @Juraj Like [This](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgDusyVPFjOrglWeWee06WbLD3lx)?

Comment: The `voltage = 0.9848815 * voltage + 0.125354;` code almost calibrated the reading with ~ -60mV steady difference (it can't measure below 130mV though), where did you get those values? can you please explain more with math included?

Comment: @newbie: I am an old timer who likes text-mode programs rather than Excel, Calc and such, so I used gnuplot. See expanded answer.

Comment: @newbie, column B should have a function in cells. and the function should use two other cells with the coefficients you want to fine-tune

Comment: @Juraj I've never used excel before and have no idea how to do what you want me do to...

Comment: @newbie, example https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/tree/master/util/Calc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right that the Arduino ADC is not accurate.  If you read the datasheet ([ATMega328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) section 28.9, ADC Characteristics) you can see a lot of "error" and "non-linearity" characteristics.

These all add up to inaccuracies in your readings.  For example the "Offset error" at your VREF could be as much as ±4.4mV, and the "Gain error" the same. Non-linearity can be as bad as 2mV, etc.

The Arduino ADC is not meant to be accurate. It's meant to be simple and cheap to implement. (It is a "Successive Approximation ADC" - approximation here is the keyword...) If you want a higher accuracy then there are more suitable ADC chips available that give that accuracy.

Comment: I was expecting 100mV error to be steady like 1.100V, 2.100V ... Wasted so much time calibrating this ...! beside using external ADC do you think it's good idea to switch to a PIC micro-controller with 12bit ADC. i'm asking this because PIC is cheaper.

Comment: I would always say use a PIC over an ATMega, but then I am a PIC junkie- however increased resolution does not equate to increased accuracy. It's still an SAR with the inherent inaccuracies which that gives you. Since the inaccuracy looks to be pretty linear you can use calibration and calculations to remove it. You have a straight line, the formula for which (if you remember school maths classes) is `y = mx + c`

Comment: Re “successive approximation ADC”: any measurement whatsoever is always an approximation. The keyword here is “successive”: it means the ADC works by iteratively refining the approximation.

Comment: @EdgarBonet And because the sampled voltage is stored in a tiny capacitor, and it's impossible to read a voltage without drawing *some* current, each successive comparison will affect the voltage across that capacitor making it less accurate with each bit that is approximated. So it's successively worse approximation. It's a successive approximation that can only ever be approximate.