# How to read voltage using ADS1115

Tags: c++, voltage-divider

I'm very new to this. I found [this tutorial](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-voltage-measurements/arduino-ads1115-module-getting-started-tutorial/).

But it don't explain how to read voltages higher than Arduino 5V. I have connected a 100K ohm resistor to positive and 10K ohm to negative of my 24V power supply.

I need some guidance for writing the code for this specific ADC, please.

Comment: So you want to measure the voltage of your power supply?

Comment: Yes i want to measure voltages higher than 5V.

Comment: You cannot measure much more than 5V with that device neither. (VDD +0.3V)
You and that "tutorial") use an adafruit library and should get information from them.
If those 2 resistors (100k + 10k) build a voltage divider and negative is connected to GND, 24V is reduced to 24V/11 ~ 2.18V between the two resistors.

Comment: i know that Datafiddler but i don't know how can i convert and read that 2,18V to 24V!

Comment: It's called "math". For example: Arduino has 10 bit precision and usually 5V reference voltage. That means one step is  5V / 1024 = 0.004883V. And if you divide input voltage by 11, that means you have to multiply previous result by 11 too.

Comment: i did what you said: voltage = voltage * 11 but it's showing lower voltage than actual voltage.

Comment: If you try something and it doesn't work as expected, please write this information into the question (not the comments). You wrote, that you tried the calculation and got lower voltages. So write in your question: the code that you used for calculation with all relevant values, what voltages are outputted by it and what voltages you measured how externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KIIV mentioned you need to do the math:

Use [this](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator) online voltage divider calculator to calculate your maximum input.

- Keep in mind you shouldn't exceed Arduino 5V.
- Use a multimeter to measure the resistors actual resistance.
- Do the math for your example assuming R1 is exactly 100K and R2 10K you have to multiple the voltage by 11.
- remember any error is going to multiple by 11 too, so make sure the first reading is accurate/stable.

ADS1115 is actually 15bit which will give you resolution of 32768, with default PGA setting you get:
`6.144 / 32768 = 0.0001875V` per bit.

```
Voltage = (your ADC reading) * 0.0001875V;
Voltage = Voltage * 11;
```

Take a look at [This](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69261/arduino-10bit-adc-is-not-accurate/69266) question/answer to see how I did reduced Arduino ADC noise, some steps can be done for ADS1115 as well.